# converting json to associative array in laravel?

Tags: php, json, laravel-4, user-permissions, cartalyst-sentry

I want to send user permissions (sentry) to a blade page.user permission is a json object(as I know).
it's controller code:

```
 $user = Sentry::findUserByID($id);
 $gr = Sentry::findGroupByName('admin');

    $permissions = $gr->permissions;
    $per = json_decode($permissions);
   return Redirect::route('admin_permit_user')->with('per', $per);
```

but it gave me this error:

```
json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array give
```

ok and when I send     $permissions before convert it by     json_decode .I get the error:

```
   Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException
```

and in the url I see something like this:

```
   /admin/user/permission/%7Bid%7D
```

is there anyway to convert json file to array? or what is my wrong? thanks for time.

Comment: Can you show what `print_r($permissions)` gives?

Comment: @Darren :thanks for reply .yes it gives for example :    Array ( [blog] => 1 )

Comment: It isn't a json object, it's an array with one item in it (Called `blog` with a a value of `1`)

Comment: @Darren: I have thought like you but I searched and found that the sentry permissions returns json object. in the other hand if it is an array so I should be able to send it by :`return Redirect::route('admin_permit_user')->with('permissions', $permissions);`.but when I run it .I see in url something like that:/admin/user/permission/   ` %7Bid%7D `. and error in page:    `Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException`

Comment: Update your question and put the errors you get there.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how the route is defined, but first thing to repair:

```
return Redirect::route('admin_permit_user', $param);
```

it is clear expects some parameter and you are not giving it one, thys that stange strings.

Comment: thanks for reply .`  $per = json_decode($permissions);

        return Redirect::route('admin_permit_user', $per);` but it gives me the same error

Comment: but does the url changed from `/admin/user/permission/%7Bid%7D`  to something meaningful?

Comment: that `$param` should hold what goes instead of `%7Bid%7D`